# Audio fails to work after connecting an HDMI monitor with an audio device

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

I had audio working on a headless system, then I connected a monitor via HDMI which had speakers on it. The audio started playing out of the monitor speakers automatically.

When I disconnect the monitor I can no longer get audio to play out of the original sound port that worked.

`pacmd list-cards` now shows 9 cards available, it used to only have 1 before I added the monitor.

```
$ pacmd list-cards
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 9 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_06_00.1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 5
        properties:
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf9080000 irq 72"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:06:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:08.0/0000:06:00.1/sound/card1"
```

Many of the new cards listed in `pacmd list-cards` seem to be webcams, which aren't even audio devices:

```
index: 5
    name: <alsa_card.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_4C329CAE-02-C930e_3>
```

I've tried `pacmd set-default-sink 0` counting up from 0 until I get an error to see if I can set the right audio device that way.

I've tried rebooting to no avail.

I've set the volume with `pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 90%` and verified the speakers work.

```
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Also, sometimes I get into this state where `pacmd` fails.

```
$ pacmd
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

I can fix that by `export $(dbus-launch)` and running `pulseaudio &`. But I don't really understand why I did that, I just found a tidbit on some related question that suggested it.

Verified that the default audio device is correct:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index'
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
  * index: 2
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
```

I haven't touched the system wide defaults in `/etc/pulse/` as far as I know. I have tried deleting the local settings in `~/.config/pulse/`